# Sitecore: How to get the class entered in General Link field

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

In the `General Link` field content author will set some class.

I want to change the class while rendering, so I used the reflector and got the code of `Link.cs` and trying to extend the `PopulateParameters` method and looks like `this.CssStyle` and `this.CssClass` are always blank. Is there any way to get the value of class entered in the `General Link` field?

[image]

Comment: Instead of changing the class, you could just use a descendant selector to change the style: `.somethingelse .static { /*style me*/ }`. If you need to do something page wide then attach the class to your body tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cast your field to `LinkField` class and use `Class` property:

```cs
LinkField field = Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["Link"];
string cssClass = field.Class;
```

---

**EDIT: **

If you want to change behaviour of Sitecore `sc:link` to change css class of every link, you need to add your own processor to the `renderField` pipeline:

```cs
public class UpdateLinkClass
{
  public void Process(Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.RenderFieldArgs args)
  {
    if (args != null && (args.FieldTypeKey == "link" || args.FieldTypeKey == "general link"))
    {
      Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField linkField = args.Item.Fields[args.FieldName];
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(linkField.Class))
      {
        args.Parameters["class"] = linkField.Class + "-custom";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and register it before `GetLinkFieldValue` processor:

```cs
<processor type="My.Assembly.Namespace.UpdateLinkClass, My.Assembly" />
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetLinkFieldValue, Sitecore.Kernel" />
```

Comment: Thank you. But I want to make this change in one place rather than everywhere the Link field is used.

Comment: Do you use field renderer to display the value of general field? Which Sitecore version you use?

Comment: I am using the sc:Link and I am using 7.2